# Number of positive real roots of $t \mapsto c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2/t^2 + c_3 / \sinh^2(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Here $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are constants bounded in absolute value by one, and at least one of them is nonzero. It seems "obvious" from looking at graphs that the answer is at most three. Rolle's Theorem leads nowhere for me since the derivative is more complicated than the function itself. By changing variables $t\to -\log u$ and manipulating things a bit, I can show that the roots occur at intersections of the functions $\log^2u$ and $$\frac{{c_2} (u-1)^2 u}{{c_1} (u-1)^2-4 {c_3} u^2}$$ for $u\in [0,1]$. From here it is tempting to invoke a [false theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686729/intersection-between-two-increasing-concave-functions) that monotone convex functions have at most two intersections.

The only other option I can think of is to break the parameter space into pieces and make clever use of inequalities on each portion of the space. This seems like a lot of work, so before going that route I wondered if there are any other tricks I am missing.

Comment: I think you will need a numerical method!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, it's clear that there is no closed-form solution for the roots. Here I am searching for a theoretical guarantee that my numerical method has, in fact, found all of the roots.

Comment: Then give an example for the values of the coefficients!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner As noted in the question, the coefficients can take on any value between -1 and 1. The specific values change from run to run as a function of the data.

Comment: Ok, i will try it.

Comment: I have considered $$c_1=c_2=-1,c_3=1$$ and i get $$t\approx 169.7106478$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks for your help. To reiterate, I am not looking for a specific root of this function. For fixed values of $c_1,c_2,c_3$, that is trivial to accomplish. Rather, I am trying to prove that the total number of (real, non-negative) solutions to the equation $c_1 e^{-2t} + c_2/t^2 + c_3 / \sinh^2(t) = 0$ is at most three.